# How can I convert MVC Route to parameter of type Boolean?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, routes

**Change route segment into boolean**

I have a simple action method in my controller and would like to pass a boolean value to my action when the string "Company" is passed in the url.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(Boolean ? isCompany) {  }
```

**I would like to call it like this.**

```
http://mysite/Feature/Configure/Company
```

So basically, when "Company" is in the url then pass **isCompany** as **true** boolean.

Is this possible?

According to the answer below I think I should then use the following mapping.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "FeatureConfigure",
    url: "Feature/Configure/{company}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Feature", action="Configure", 
       company = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

public ActionResult Configure(String company) {
   var isCompany = company == "Company";
   // maybe use a switch if there are multiple values company can be
   // and probably rename the variable to something more generic.
}
```

Comment: Do you have other cases where that path might match? i.e would you possibly have `/feature/configure/user` or even just `/feature/configure/`.

Comment: There are two possibilities? I changed the code to reflect a little more concern with the company variable for anyone who would need to have multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, you'd have to handle it like:

```
public ActionResult DoSometing(string foo)
{
    var isCompany = foo == "Company";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really comes back to what you are trying to achieve. 
Having a check on an input like this, suggests that you will be planning to have a fork in your logic and possibly display different content/views.

Simpler option would be to let MVC handle it and keep your code cleaner.

**Option 1:**

Changing the `{company}` portion of your route to `{action}` and fork your logic at the action level.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "FeatureConfigure",
url: "Feature/Configure/{action}",
defaults: new { controller = "Feature", action="Index" }
);

public ActionResult Company() {
    // Do company stuff
}

public ActionResult Branch() {
    // Do branch stuff
}
```

**Option 2:**

Same as above but using route attributes (assuming you're using MVC5).
To do that remove the `FeatureConfigure` route from the config.

Then include the following on the controller and actions:

```
[RoutePrefix("features/configure")]
public class FeatureController : Controller
{
    ....
    [Route("{type:regex(company)}")]
    public ActionResult Company()
    {
        // do company stuff
    }

    [Route("{type:regex(branch)}")]
    public ActionResult Branch()
    {
        // do branch stuff
    }

    ...
}
```

**Note:** in either case it would probably make more sense to rename `FeatureController` to `ConfigureContoller` but that's up to you